# Conditional WHERE performance issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables.   ACCOUNTS, CONTACTS AND OPPORTUNITIES.   I need to be able to bring up a list of ACCOUNTS, that have OPPORTUNITIES with matching OPPORTUNITY field AND ACCOUNTS with matching ACCOUNTNAME field.

If no ACCOUNTNAME or OPPORTUNITY is provided, all ACCOUNTS show

OPPORTUNITIES are related to CONTACTS and CONTACTS to ACCOUNTS as below:

```
ACCOUNTS
¦
CONTACTS
¦
OPPORTUNITIES
```

I had created a stored procedure to perform this search, which has input parameters for @accountname and @opportunity, but it keeps timing out when I supply an @opportunity value.   There are only 9000 records in the OPPORTUNITIES table, so not a huge amount.

I have taken the essence from the stored procedure to test the SQL code, but it is still taking 2 minutes to execute, when I provide a value for @opportunity.  Obviously when a stored procedure, it would be set to null unless the input parameter had a value.

```
declare @opportunity nvarchar(100) = 'searchtext' */ or null /*
declare @accountname nvarchar(100)  = ''

select 
ACCOUNTS.ACCOUNTNAME
FROM ACCOUNTS
WHERE
ACCOUNTS.ACCOUNTNAME LIKE '%'+@accountname+'%'
AND
(
    @opportunity is null
    OR
    ACCOUNTS.ACCOUNTID IN (select CONTACTS.ACCOUNTID from OPPORTUNITIES INNER JOIN CONTACTS ON OPPORTUNITIES.CONTACTID=CONTACTS.CONTACTID  WHERE OPPORTUNITY LIKE '%'+@opportunity+'%')
)
```

It's weird, because if I remove `@opportunity is null OR` , it executes quickly.

I appreciate this is something to do with the way execution is performed behind the scenes, that I do not fully understand.

Please bear in mind, when offering a solution, that the stored procedure I'm working on has other search parameters that search other tables along the lines of :

```
WHERE
ACCOUNTS.ACCOUNTNAME LIKE '%'+@accountname+'%'
AND
(
    @opportunity is null
    OR
    ACCOUNTS.ACCOUNTID IN (select CONTACTS.ACCOUNTID from OPPORTUNITIES INNER JOIN CONTACTS ON OPPORTUNITIES.CONTACTID=CONTACTS.CONTACTID  WHERE OPPORTUNITY LIKE '%'+@opportunity+'%')
)
AND
(
    @otherinput is null
    OR
    ACCOUNTS.ACCOUNTID IN (select ACCOUNTID FROM SOMETHINGELSE WHERE SOMETHING LIKE '%'+@otherinput +'%')
)
AND
(
    @otherinput2 is null
    OR
    ACCOUNTS.ACCOUNTID IN (select ACCOUNTID FROM SOMETHINGELSE2 WHERE SOMETHING2 LIKE '%'+@otherinput2 +'%')
)
```

but wanted to simplify the example for the purposes of this question.

Comment: Catch all, or kitchen sink, queries are known to have caveats on performance. Both Gail Shaw and Aaron Bertrand have done great articles on them if you do a quick search.

Comment: That leading wildcard, however, is never going to be SARGable.

Comment: Please post table definitions (inc. indexing) and your EXPLAIN.

Comment: Suggest you read about conditional search from [Erland](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) and [Aaron](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input above.  I did some additional research and discovered "option (recompile)", which has solved the problem for now.  I appreciate my queries are not efficient and I will take onboard the above comments.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest rewriting the `IN` using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT a.ACCOUNTNAME
FROM ACCOUNTS a
WHERE a.ACCOUNTNAME LIKE '%'+@accountname+'%' AND
     (@opportunity IS NULL OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM OPPORTUNITIES o JOIN
                   CONTACTS c
                   ON o.CONTACTID = c.CONTACTID 
              WHERE c.OPPORTUNITY LIKE '%' + @opportunity + '%' AND
                    a.ACCOUNTID = c.ACCOUNTID 
             )
     );
```

This allows the query to use indexes on:  `CONTACTS(ACCOUNTID, CONTACTID)` and `OPPORTUNITIES(CONTACTID, OPPORTUNITY)`.

That said, this query is going to require lots of full table scans.  I would ask if you can find a way to avoid using `LIKE` with wildcards.  Perhaps you might find that full text indexes are useful for what you want to do.